# PHP: php mail(), how to setup php mail function without smtp on my own linux server?

Tags: php

I would like to know is there a way to setup php mail() so that it works when I use mail() function? I only have the right to use ftp in my server for me to transfer files, is there a way to use some type of php file or code to help me use/setup mail() function. I am using this function for my website contact us form. Perhaps, is there another to send free email to myself as user clicks the submit button? Because I only purchase a domain account with other people's server available for ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most servers sendmail or postfix (or something like that) is enabled by default AFAIK so it probably already works.

If it doesn't ask your hoster to enable it for you.

Comment: agreed you should try it first without smtp and sendmail likely will already work. +1

Comment: It is telling me how it ("Fails to send mail, fails to find host address"

Comment: Warning: mail(): Failed to send mail. (failed to resolve host address.) in /volume1/web/xxxxxxxx on line X

Comment: I used exactly this :mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

Comment: And of course i have something inside each variable. I just don't know why it is not working? Do i need to setup anything in my domain or server??

Comment: @RyanFung What do you have setup for mail settings when you do: `phpinfo()`. Do you see sendmail being setup?

Comment: it says no value in those mail field

Comment: it says localhost in the smtp section

Comment: @RyanFung In some cases you would have access to the `php.ini` file of your website using ftp if that is the case try to setup sendmail (typically something like `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`, but this is depending on the server and installation) on de server if that fails or you don't have access to the file I would just contact your hoster and let them either change it to use sendmail or let them fix the smtp settings so that it works on your site.